# Entity Framework detach entity not working

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, serialization

I'm implementing some generic auditing in my class. All I want is to detach an entity from the context and serialize it and save the JSON string of the serialized entity in the db as part of my audit logic. But because some objects have references obviously the serializing fails for that reason. So I implemented logic to set to null for all `class.PropertyType.IsGenericType` and works fine. But after creating my audit log and call the `context.SaveChanges`, it saves the entity that I unset some properties changes as well even I did actually detach it from the context.

Anyway I can make this code work?

**NOTE**: The newItem is actually still being tracked by the context...

```
context.Entry<T>( newItem ).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached;
context.SaveChanges();

var props = newItem.GetType().GetProperties().Where( p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType );

foreach ( var item in props )
{
   item.SetValue( newItem, null );
}

AuditLog log = new AuditLog()
{
   CreatedOn = DateTime.Now,
   ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now,
   Type = ( Int32 ) activity,
   ActionTable = newItem.GetType().Name,
   Userid = ( ( CurrentUser != null ) ? CurrentUser.Id : 0 ),
   AfterImage = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize( newItem ),
   ModifiedBy = ( ( CurrentUser != null ) ? CurrentUser.Email : "System" ),
   Comments = String.Format( "Created a new {0}", newItem.GetType().Name ),
   BeforeImage = ( oldItem != null ) ? new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize( oldItem ) : String.Empty,
   ObjectId = ( Int32 ) newItem.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault( x => x.Name == "Id" ).GetValue( newItem ),
   Parameters = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize( HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values )
};

context.Logs.Add( log );
context.SaveChanges(); // When I execute this, the changes in the foreach loop are saved for that newItem
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get newItem with ChangeTracking enabled? because I do think when you set the values of newItem, EF will set the entityState to modified. If you want to avoid this, try gathering newItem with .AsNoTracking().

Comment: I don't see a reason for the `SaveChanges()` call after detaching an entity...

Comment: @ErikPhilips, it was just my effort in trying to make it work...
@DevilSuichiro, newItem is from creating a new item. This is how it partly looks like:

`context.Set<T>().Add( item );
context.SaveChanges();

using ( AuditLogService service = new AuditLogService() )
{
      // This calls the above source code in the OP...
      service.Create<T>( ActivityTypes.Create, item ); 
}`
It looks to me that Entity Framework is tracking the item after it's created and I am not sure how to escape that.